# Yii1 findAll by date is always return empty result

Tags: php, yii

This may look simple, but I'm kinda frustrated with this. I would like to search all invoice in a certain date

```
$invoices = SalesInvoice::model()->findAll('DATE(t.invoice_date) >= "2017-04-01" AND DATE(t.invoice_date) <= "2017-04-29"');

$invoices2 = SalesInvoice::model()->findAll('t.invoice_date = "2017-04-26 06:56:16"');

$invoices3 = SalesInvoice::model()->findAll('DATE(t.invoice_date) = "2017-04-26"');
```

Those always return empty results. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: What's the type of invoice_date column in db?

Comment: @G45 The type is datetime

Answer (score 1):

If you are using yii 1 try this.

```
$invoice_date ='2017-04-26 06:56:16';
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = "invoice_date =:invoice_date";
$criteria->params = array(':invoice_date' => $invoice_date);
$invoices2 = SalesInvoice::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

OR

```
$invoices2 = SalesInvoice::model()->findAll(
                  array(
                      'condition' => 'invoice_date = :invoice_date',
                      'params'    => array(':invoice_date' => '2017-04-26 06:56:16')
                  )
              );
```

For yii2

```
$invoices2 = SalesInvoice::findAll(['invoice_date' =>'2017-04-26 06:56:16']);
```

OR

```
$invoices2 = SalesInvoice::find()->where(['invoice_date' =>'2017-04-26 06:56:16'])->all();
```

Comment: I'm using Yii1, didn't work, still return empty results

Comment: @HenryGunawan strange before anser your question I have tested in my local system can you share your table schema and module